# JPA Repository delete by a list of a composed PK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository

I'm trying to do a remove with a JPA repository by naming convention (not using @Query).

The point is that I have an `@EmbeddedId`, so the repo header looks like

```
public interface MatchPronosticsRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, MyID>
```

So by default I have a method `delete(MyID id)`, but I need something like `delete(Iterable<? extends MyID>)` so I can kill some objects with one shot. Any idea on how to solve it? Not finding it

thanks !

### EDIT

I've tried adding `void deleteByMatchPronosticPk (Iterable<? extends MatchPronosticPK> ids);`
But the result is weird. It seems to be doing a Select which would be fine, but using 3 fields, and 3 values, but only 2 placeholders :S

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        matchprono0_.match_id as match3_4_,
        matchprono0_.isprimary as isprimar1_4_,
        matchprono0_.user_id as user4_4_,
        matchprono0_.match_result as match2_4_ 
    from
        match_pronostics matchprono0_ 
    where
        (
            matchprono0_.match_id, matchprono0_.isprimary, matchprono0_.user_id
        )=(
            ? , ?
        )
2015-06-03 21:41:18,149  TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 58
2015-06-03 21:41:18,149  TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BOOLEAN] - true
2015-06-03 21:41:18,149  TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - 26
2015-06-03 21:41:18,149  WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22023
2015-06-03 21:41:18,149  ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
```

### Workaround for now

Need to continue with some other stuff... As the delete was internally doing a Select before attempting the delete, this will not harm the performance more than the original code I was trying to achieve

```
List<MatchPronostic> pronosticsToDelete = matchPronosticsRepository.findAll(ids);
matchPronosticsRepository.deleteInBatch(pronosticsToDelete);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not @Query, but how about having a custom method for you repository as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)

So basically, i am suggesting something like this:

```
public void myCustomDel(Iterable<MyID> ids) {
  delete(findAll(ids));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically the "workaround" I've posted. Your option may be implemented with new J8 default methods so it can be kept in the JPA interface. But I thought there was going to be an option to delete based on a list, without needing to go and get the entities first